# Шифрование строки в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, криптография, шифрование

Создать программу, которая запрашивает у пользователя произвольную строку символов.
  Далее программа ее шифрует и выводит на экран в зашифрованном виде. Шифрование происходит путем замены каждого символа символом, который находится на 5 позиций правее в предопределенной таблице шифрования.
  Таблица шифрования задается программистом в виде одномерного списка символов латинского алфавита от `a` до `z`. Если при выборе символа для шифровки таблица шифрования заканчивается, то циклически переходить к ее началу.
 Отсутствующие в таблице шифрования символы, записываются в результирующую строку без изменений. Регистр игнорируется.
Таблица шифрования `(a,b,c,d,...,x,y,z,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`.
Например: Исходная строка, которую ввел пользователь: `'secret'`, `'Office 365'`
    Зашифрованная строка, которую выдала программа: `'xjhwjy'`, `'tkknhj 8ba'`
    Примечание: т.н. таблица шифрования может быть представлена как строка или список.

> def encode(str_to_encode): # returns enсoded string
>           pass

Не мог понять как заставить `python` учитывать пробелы, но не менять их....

```
import string
str_to_encode = input("Введите фразу для кодировки: ")
def encode(str_to_encode):
    coded_string = ""
    code_method = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
    code_method = list(code_method)
    for i in range(len(str_to_encode)):
        for j in range(len(code_method)):
            if str_to_encode[i] == code_method[j]:
                coded_string += str(code_method[(j + 5) % len(code_method)])

    return coded_string

print("Закодированная фраза:", encode(str_to_encode))
```

Comment: Вы не знаете как сравнить символ с пробелом? Или оператор continue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

То, что в вопросе описано называется [Шифром Цезаря](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F):

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits
alphabet_list = ascii_letters + digits


def caesar_code(text, shift):
    shift_text = ''

    for c in text:
        if c not in alphabet_list:
            shift_text += c
            continue

        i = (alphabet_list.index(c) + shift) % len(alphabet_list)
        shift_text += alphabet_list[i]

    return shift_text
```

[Использование:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/b5f67ef853d0ef1f4d39b6614179c49a3726ad25/caesar_code/caesar_code.py)

```
text = "secret Office 365"

# С учетом регистра
print(caesar_code(text, shift=5))  # xjhwjy Tkknhj 8ba

# Без учета регистра
print(caesar_code(text.lower(), shift=5))  # xjhwjy tkknhj 8ba
```

Comment: А это не копипаста, а упрощенный код, который я сам писал. Переименуйте функцию и захардкорте сдвиг, если смущает предложенное мной

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться строковым методом [translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), который возвращает копию переданной строки с заменой тех символов, которые присутствуют в таблице замен.

Таблица замен создается с помощью статического строкового метода [maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans). В данном случае таблица замен будет сконструирована из полного алфавита используемых символов и его копии с заданным смещением.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, digits

src_chars = ascii_lowercase + digits
LEN_ALPH = len(src_chars)

def cesarize(inp, shift):

    # "периодичность" алфавита на случай, если смещение больше его (алфавита) длины
    shift = shift if shift < LEN_ALPH else shift % LEN_ALPH        

    # копия алфавита с заданным смещением
    shift_chars = src_chars[shift:] + src_chars[:shift] 

    # создание таблицы соответствия
    trans_table = str.maketrans(src_chars, shift_chars) 

    # приведение входной строки к нижнему регистру -> возврат закодированной последовательности
    return inp.lower().translate(trans_table)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    example_arg = "secret Office 365", 5
    print(cesarize(*example_arg)) # -> xjhwjy tkknhj 8ba
```

Так как пробельного символа нет в таблице соответствия, пробелы будут сохранятся в неизменном виде, специальной обработки их как частного случая не требуется.