# Скрытие логина и пароля в коде Python

Tags: python

Каким образом можно зашифровать логин с паролем в самом коде? Ну или каким-либо другим способом сделать так, чтобы нельзя было бы их получить другим людям, так как сам код должен быть открытым и доступным для просмотра другими людьми.

```
conn = pymysql.connect(
    host="xxc.ru",
    port=3306,
    user="user",
    password="password",
    db="test",
    charset='utf8'
)
```

Есть ли смысл использования в данном случае [шифра Цезаря](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F), как в [данном](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/761499/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-python) вопросе?

Comment: Всё, что может быть расшифровано, будет расшифровано. Вам зачем шифровать?

Comment: @andreymal чтобы это не выглядело так открыто как это на самом деле есть

Comment: Просто не показывать это другим глазам — самый лучший и единственный надёжный способ скрыть это ;) Все так делают, и почему вы не можете делать так же, мне пока непонятно

Comment: Храните пароль в текстовом файле, читайте его из файла и этот файл никому не показывайте, хоспаде. Никогда не надо писать пароли прямо в коде! Код отдельно, пароли в текстовом файле отдельно - и ничего не надо шифровать. Хотя вариант с переменными окружения из принятого вами ответа тоже вариант.

Comment: Раз для вас шифрование оказалось необязательным условием, позволил себе переформулировать ваш вопрос, надеюсь вы не против

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70888/discussion-on-question-by--------python).

Comment: @Дмитрий кстати, небольшое замечание не по теме вопроса: не советую использовать кодировку `utf8` в MySQL, так как с ней есть проблемы с некоторыми символами вроде Emoji; лучше перейти на `utf8mb4`. См. [«MySQL обрезает текст на сложном символе-картинке»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/446408)

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Is it safe to store critical passwords in server environment variables?](https://superuser.com/q/708355/13868) и [Secure database password stored in an env variable](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/83180/438)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Шифр Цезаря быстренько вскроет любой сообразительный студент <s>вроде меня</s>.

Мухи отдельно, котлеты отдельно: просто не пишите пароль внутри кода, и проблема будет решена сама собой. Кроме того, для подключения к какой-нибудь другой базе данных не нужно будет редактировать код, что повышает удобство. А вот где тогда писать пароль — тут уже много вариантов.

### Переменная окружения

В любой «взрослой» ОС есть некие глобальные переменные, именуемые переменными окружения (переменные среды, environment variables). Можно положить пароль туда, а в питоне читать эти переменные. Как менять переменные окружения, зависит от конкретной ОС (можно детали [в Википедии почитать](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B)), а в коде Python их чтение может выглядеть как-нибудь так:

```
import os, pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(
    host="xxc.ru",
    user=os.getenv('MYSQL_USER'),
    password=os.getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
    # ...
)
```

В данном примере логин читается из переменной окружения `MYSQL_USER`, а пароль из `MYSQL_PASSWORD`.

### Простой текстовый файл

Суть проста: пишем пароль в любом текстовом редакторе, сохраняем в текстовый файл, а потом читаем этот файл в питоне.

```
with open('mysql_user.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as fp:
    mysql_user = fp.read().rstrip()

with open('mysql_password.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as fp:
    mysql_password = fp.read().rstrip()

conn = pymysql.connect(
    host="xxc.ru",
    user=mysql_user,
    password=mysql_password,
    # ...
)
```

В данном примере логин и пароль читаются из файлов `mysql_user.txt` и `mysql_password.txt`, находящихся в текущем каталоге.

Немного пояснений, почему я читаю файлы именно так:

- правила хорошего тона предписывают явно закрывать открытые файлы после их использования. Это очень удобно делать с помощью конструкции `with`;
- UTF-8 — самая лучшая кодировка на свете, поэтому я прописал её и советую её использовать везде и всегда. Но есть нюанс: виндовый Блокнот добавляет [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) в начале текстового файла, и для его корректной обработки питоном я прописал кодировку `utf-8-sig`, а не просто `utf-8`;
- некоторые текстовые редакторы добавляют перенос строки в конце файла, поэтому я его удаляю с помощью `rstrip()`, чтоб не мешался.

### Полноценный файл конфигурации

Высока вероятность, что вы захотите хранить отдельно от кода не только логин и пароль, так почему бы не завести полноценный конфиг? Можно создать, к примеру, такой файл `config.ini`:

```
[mysql]
user = логин
password = пароль
```

А потом распарсить его в питоне:

```
import configparser, pymysql
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini', encoding='utf-8-sig')

conn = pymysql.connect(
    host="xxc.ru",
    user=config.get('mysql', 'user'),
    password=config.get('mysql', 'password'),
    # ...
)
```

`ConfigParser` — очень мощная и универсальная штука; рекомендую почитать [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) хотя бы для общего развития.

Если вы захотите выложить свой код публично на какой-нибудь GitHub, не забудьте добавить свои файлы со всеми паролями в `.gitignore`, чтобы случайно не опубликовать и их тоже.

### Python-модуль с переменными

Можно создать Python-файл, например, `local_settings.py`, прописать в нём переменные с логином и паролем:

```
MYSQL_USER = 'Вася'
MYSQL_PASSWORD = '123456'
```

И потом обращаться к ним после импорта:

```
import local_settings as settings

conn = pymysql.connect(
    host="xxc.ru",
    user=settings.MYSQL_USER,
    password=settings.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    # ...
)
```

Так как `local_settings.py` является полноценным Python-файлом, там можно выполнять какой-нибудь произвольный код, что увеличивает гибкость в сравнении с текстовыми файлами, но в то же время открывает новые способы для выстрела в ногу, так что аккуратно.

Файл должен быть расположен так, чтобы Python его смог найти и импортировать. Он не во всех окружениях может импортировать файлы из текущего каталога, и, если простой импорт как в примере выше у вас не сработает, возможно понадобится прописать переменную окружения `PYTHONPATH=.` или добавить текущий каталог в список `sys.path`.

Кстати, все связанные с файлами способы можно комбинировать с переменными окружения. Суть такова: в переменной окружения прописываем, что читать, а Python-код потом читает указанный там файл (или импортирует указанный модуль):

`SETTINGS_MODULE=my_mysql_settings`

```
import os, importlib
# Это значение по умолчанию на случай, если переменной окружения не будет
os.environ.setdefault('SETTINGS_MODULE', 'local_settings')

# Импортируем модуль, указанный в переменной окружения
settings = importlib.import_module(os.getenv('SETTINGS_MODULE'))

# Остальное как обычно
conn = pymysql.connect(
    host="xxc.ru",
    user=settings.MYSQL_USER,
    password=settings.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    # ...
)
```

Таким образом можно завести несколько файлов конфигурации и переключаться между ними с помощью переменной окружения. Подобный подход (в виде более сложном, чем я показал, но похоже) применяется, например, в популярном веб-фреймворке Django; там такая переменная окружения называется `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`.

### Вообще не хранить ничего и запрашивать в консоли каждый раз

Вбивать пароль от базы данных каждый раз не очень удобно, но всё же тоже вариант. При этом с использованием `getpass` вводимый текст в консоли не отображается (даже звёздочек нету), так что никто не узнает, какой пароль вы там вводите.

```
import getpass, pymysql

mysql_user = getpass.getpass('MySQL user> ')
mysql_password = getpass.getpass('MySQL password> ')

conn = pymysql.connect(
    host="xxc.ru",
    user=mysql_user,
    password=mysql_password,
    # ...
)
```

Comment: Мб, добавить пример использования `config.py` для хранения логинов/паролей? Достаточно будет сделать импорт такого модуля и вытащить из него переменные

Comment: @gil9red в принципе можно, но лично мне этот способ не кажется хорошим

Comment: мне он показался лучше обычных текстовых файлов. Плюс, в нем можно условия писать, типо: `password = "..."` `if DEBUG: password = "qwerty"`, что иногда выгоднее других вариантов

Comment: @gil9red `debug_config.ini` :)

Answer (score 8):

Если на винде на вашей машине, то можно создать две переменые окружения и хранить в них. А в программе явно читать переменную окружения с именем скажем USERPYTHON PASSWORDSQL и пользоваться их значением таким образом скрываемым от глаз учеников ваши данные))

Comment: Или хранить файл конфига в папке проекта, например в [config.py](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/master/PyGithub_examples)

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys
import keyring
import getpass
my_server = '192.168.0.1'
def windows_credential():
    # look there: cmd -> control userpasswords2 -> Advanced -> Manage passwd -> Windows Credential
    passwd = getpass.getpass(prompt='Please input password for account: ')
    keyring.set_password(my_server, getpass.getuser(), passwd)
    print('The Windows credential was sucessfully created for host: {} and user: {}'.format(my_server, getpass.getuser()))
def get_passwd():
    passwd = keyring.get_password(my_server, getpass.getuser())
    if passwd is None:
        print('Please create windows credential for host')
        sys.exit(1)
    return passwd
windows_credential()
print(get_passwd())
```

обычно зашифрованные пароли хранят в БД , если не планируется использовать БД то в локальном хранилище Credential manager - хранилище шифрует все за вас.
keyring так же работает и с linux credentials.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Используйте или конфиг-файл, который хранится там, куда не доберутся загребущие ручки чьи-то, либо шифруйте, но серьезно, так, чтобы расшифровывать без ключа было долго и муторно, например, через DES.